# GCS permission recovery

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-storage

I have screwed up royally with google-cloud-storage recently when I deleted all permissions from a bucket. Now this bucket is basically untouchable (except for read), how can I regain permission over my bucket?

Comment: If you're the bucket owner you should still be able to edit the bucket permissions. Have you tried using the gsutil acl ch command to add permissions again?

Comment: I have my gcloud sdk credentials set as owner of my project that includes said bucket. I tried to call gsutil acl ch -u myemail@blah.com:O gs://said-bucket. However, it fails saying that I do not have owner-role access to it.
You can in fact delete ALL permissions for a certain bucket, and I think I deleted the owner policy over that bucket along with a bunch of other policies.

Comment: What do you get when you run: gsutil acl get gs://said-bucket  ?

Comment: The new IAM api/UI allows removing the resource owner.  The recovery mechanism is for a project admin to grant setIamPolicy access at the project level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a recovery mechanism you (or a project administrator) can grant yourself the Storage > Storage Admin role at the project level.  This will allow you to edit the bucket policy.

Note: The Storage Admin role grants unlimited access to all Cloud Storage resources in that project.  You may want to remove the grant after you are done fixing the ACL.

Comment: Thank you good sir, I didn't realize that Storage Admin holds more power over project owner within Storage. The problem is now fixed.